# Identifying react-native TextInput instance in callback

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying too create a view that takes in a 6 digit verification coder using 6 separate 1 digit TextInput instances. I want to assign a callback to each input so I can track the user inputting the code but I can't see any obvious way to do this.

I can see a onChangeText prop but this doesn't have a way of identifying which of the six TextInputs is calling it.

I'm sure there is an easy way to do this but it's not obvious to me so I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used an onChangeText prop you could call an arrow function inside, call your desired callback, passing the 'id' of the input + the value.

Something like this:

```
<TextInput onChangeText={(text) => {
  this.yourCallback(text, 1); // 1 is the id of the input.
 }
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but with a few tweaks, it should solve your problem:

```
this.state = {
    code: []
}

onChangeText = (text, i) => {
    const code = this.state.code
    if (!Number.isNaN(text)) {
        this.setState({
            code: [...code.slice(0, i), +text, ...code.slice(i + 1)]
        })
    }
}

render(){
    return(
        {Array.from({length: 6}, (_, i) => {
            return (
                <TextInput value={this.state.code[i]} onChangeText={text => this.onChangeText(text, i)} />
            )
        })}
    )
}
```

Because of the different behavior of default JS classes like `Array` in the JS Engine V8 used in Chrome (for example) and the one used in React Native (JavaScriptCore), `Array.from` might behave differently in your app. If you are already using `lodash` or `underscore` in your project, I suggest you use `lodash.range(6).map((i) => <TextInput ... />)` instead.

Comment: Why not just `forEach` loop if you saying _...might behave differently in your app_

Comment: `forEach` does not solve the problem of generating an array of a given size (6 elements) on the fly. And hard-coding `[0,1,2,3,4,5]` to then do a `[].forEach` is not the best looking solution in my opinion. Plus being aware of the difference in the JS engines is always good to know.

Comment: i mean `for` loop, if you know the size, just loop it, `for(let i = 0; i < myMagicVariable; i++)` and push to array

Comment: Absolutely, that'd work too. It looks even better with `myMagicVariable`!. I was just suggesting new alternative :)